# How to make an event that gets executed when an if statement turns true without a timer C#

Tags: c#, events, ifs

At first i tried:

```
Dispatchertimer tick = new Dispatchertimer()
tick.Intervall = new Timespan(0,0,0,0,1);
tick.tick += Disptimertick()

void DispTimertick()
{
    if (LeftMouseButtonState == pressed)
    {
        DoSomeCode() 
    }
}
```

But Then i wanted to know if i could start an event when the if(LeftMouseButtonState == down) turns true

Comment: `if`s don't trigger *events*, however *events* ARE *events*. Research the mouse button events

Comment: Are you coding a graphical user interface /GUI? If yes, those mouse events are handled by the GUI framework, so which one do you use? (Winforms ? WPF? WinUI? UWP? Xamarin? Unity3D? ASP.NET)? Otherwise, you might need to handle the mouse events from Windows yourself, which is a bit more complicated (but feasible)

Comment: Gui WPF . But there is no event that gets triggered when a mouse is down. Only if its down in the WPF itselfs.